# How to publish a VSIX to MyGet in VSTS Release?

Tags: vsix, myget

I have a VSIX that is built in VSTS. I have a release that I want to publish that VSIX to MyGet. I can upload NuGet packages to my MyGet-NuGet feed, but I can't figure out how to upload VSIX packages to my MyGet-VSIX feed.

This link: [Publish to MyGet from a VSTS Build](http://docs.myget.org/docs/how-to/publish-to-myget-from-a-vsts-build) is only for NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a HTTP POST from your build server to the feed to add a Visual Studio extension from your continuous integration process. The POST URL is in the form of /F//vsix/upload. Note you will have to add the X-NuGet-ApiKeyheader with a valid API key as well.

Another option is adding your VSTS build as a package source to your feed. MyGet will then find the published VSIX and automatically add it to your feed.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a year too late, but I just hit this, and here's how I solved it. I'm doing this against the enterprise version of MyGet, which means I have my own domain name, but other than that things should be the same.

At the end of my build, I added a Command Line Task.

In the script section of the task, I added the following:

```
curl -X POST --verbose --data-binary @"$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\templates\Enterprise-Template\EnterpriseBotVSIX\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\EnterpriseBotTemplate.vsix" -H "X-NuGet-ApiKey: [KEY GOES HERE]" https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/aitemplates/vsix/upload
```